# Merging with null values

Tags: neo4j, merge, null, cypher

So I've been trying to load a csv file where participants have had to rate whom they will get advice from/talk to when they have problems with studying. the table looks something like this:

[image]

The alphabets are just names of the people. As you can see there are nulls in this table. I'm trying to load this into Neo4j so we can visualise who is choosing who and if this relationship is reciprocal. Any idea? All help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you show the example data. Is it just empty spaces or ""?

Answer (score 2):

Using `IS NOT NULL` can solve your problem.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:///xyz.csv AS line 
WITH line LIMIT 10
RETURN line
```

Using this you can see how your data is being loaded.(Don't forget to use limit). Since all the values loaded from CSV are in string format, you'll get your empty column values as this -> `""`.

From that you can create your node by following the blog i've referenced. And also using `IS NOT NULL` you can skip the null values and create your schema.

Example:

```
MERGE (n:Person{name:line.Person})-[:CHOSE]-(:Study1{name:line[1]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study2{name:line[2]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study3{name:line[3]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study4{name:line[4]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study5{name:line[5]})
```

OR you can use

```
WITH Line[1] as Person, Line[2] as Study1 and so on...
WHERE Study5 IS NOT NULL
MERGE (n:Person{name:line.Person})-[:CHOSE]-(:Study1{name:line[1]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study2{name:line[2]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study3{name:line[3]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study4{name:line[4]})
MERGE (n)-[:CHOSE]-(:Study5{name:line[5]})
```

For more detail go through this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/load-csv-neo4j-quickly-and).

Hope this helps!